# Mp2307 what is the maximum output current?

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, step-down

On the datasheet says minimum Upper Switch Current Limit at minimum duty cycle is 4.0A (min) 5.8A (typ).

How can i calculate the maximum output current? It will be higher or lower than 3A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datasheet 1st page says

```
3A Continuous Output Current
4A Peak Output Current
```

> The peak current is usually limited by choice of L and IC heat loss and is exceeded by upper switch max current capacity.

Comment: 4A peak putput current can not be prolonged?

Comment: NO compute thermal junction rise

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could get 4-A output current, assuming very large heatsink pad and inductance enough large to minimize current ripple. But maximum duty cycle is 90 %, so there will be also switching at 340 kHz and total losses will probably overheat the poor IC. Nobody uses components at their maximum ratings, even if it would work.